# Does the question "until what time do you work" sound natural?

Tags: prepositions, word-order, phrase-choice, wh-questions, pied-piping

Tell me please which one of the following questions sound the most natural?

> Until what time do you work?
>
> What time do you work until?
>
> What time do you work to?

Comment: "When do you get off work?" is probably more typical in AmE.

Comment: "What time do you finish work?" sounds most natural to my British ear. Your first version is correct but sounds unnaturally formal.

Comment: "What time do you finish work?" is corresponding BrE (simultaneous with other identical comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"What time do you work until?" would be the most idiomatic of the three; the third option wouldn't be said as it sounds a little ambiguous and could probably be interpreted in a few different ways.

I (British) would usually say this as:

> What time do you finish work?
>
> What time do you work till? (more colloquial)

Comment: In what ways can a native speaker take in the question: "What time do you work to?", thank you.

Comment: I suppose it's less that it would be interpreted to mean something else, and more that one might initially attempt to interpret the meaning more along the lines of, "What music do you listen to?", "What beat do you march to?", etc., which is not the same as the meaning we're trying to convey here, so it might be a little confusing.

Comment: To keep along the lines of your patterns it (time) may be iterpreted as a musical tempo, i.e. "What tempo do you work to?"

Comment: @Eugene: I did consider that, funnily enough. :)